# Increasing role claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims

I used role claims for dynamic access
I don't have any problem locally, but when on the server (Linux) the number of roll calls that include the name of the action control exceeds a certain limit, the site has problems.

Comment: Where you store the role claims, Cookie or JWT token? When the role claims not working, Whether the current user is login or logout status? You could check whether the token or cookie expired or not? Besides, you can also post the relates code or create a sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.